# Power Automate Trigger With Item Level Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, trigger

I was searching for the reason my SharePoint trigger didn't fire after creating a new item and realized when I toggled the item level permissions off, it works again!

[image]

[image]

How can I set this to 'Read items that were created by the user' and still have the Event Trigger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permission level of the account under which the workflow is running. I have plenty lists with the "read items that were created by the user" setting, and the workflow runs under a service account that has site collection admin permissions. No problems running the workflow, ever.

If site collection admin is too much for your taste, copy the Edit permission level and tick "Override List Behaviors". Users with that permission can see all items.

[image]